# Output EPS via PHP

Tags: php, ajax, image, eps

Ok here is the issue.  I need to display a list of images that can be of many different types.  The system admins decided to keep all these images outside of the webroot for security reasons.  I am using some fun php trickiness to get my images but I am not able to display the eps files and my tiffs have issues also but im more concentrated on the EPS. Oh btw we are using an MVC so the url is how we call functions and pass parameters.

This is how I display the images via a loop of image paths from the database

```
foreach($paths as $path){
    // $path = '/0/path/1/to/2/image/3/filename.eps' 
    <img src="/path/to/script/0/path/1/to/2/image/3/filename.eps" />
}
```

In that script I do the following:

```
$count = 0;
// BUILD SRC PATH FROM PASSED ARGUMENTS
while($this->_getParam($count) && $count < 30 ){
    $path[] = urldecode($this->_getParam($count));
    $count++;
}
$path = '/'.urldecode(implode('/',$path));

$srcESC = escapeshellarg($path);
$mime = exec('file -bi '.$srcESC);

if (!file_exists($path)) return;
switch($mime){
    case 'image/x-MS-bmp':
        header('Content-Type: image/x-ms-bmp');
        break;
    case 'application/postscript':
        header('Content-Type: application/postscript');
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        break;
    case 'image/x-ico':
        header('Content-Type: image/x-icon');
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        break;
    case 'application/pdf':
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        header('Content-Type: image/x-png');
        break;
    case 'image/svg+xml':
    case 'image/svg-xml':
        header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
        break;
    case 'image/x-tiff':
    case 'image/tiff':
        header('Content-Type: image/tiff');
        break;
    case 'image/x-photoshop':
    case 'application/x-quark-xpress-3':
    case 'application/pdf':
    case 'application/octet_stream':
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
    header('Content-type: application/octet');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        break;
    }
    readfile($path);
```

EPS should pick up on the application/postscript Content_Type and that is what my headers return via chrome inspect but it just wont pull the visual for the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've worked with .EPS and .TIFFs for years (circa 1988) and far as I know, a browser won't preview those, not without an available plugin, if one even exists. You could "count" the number of .EPS files that are in a folder, but you won't be able to view them as thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks man, I have been banging my head against the wall for about a week on this one.  I think the next plan is to use imagemagick to convert them to jpegs and view them that way... problem have issues with that also since the damn designers took tiffs and just placed them in an eps file (doh).

Comment: Oh lah Lord, damn's the word. I doubt anyone's ever used that word for when I was working in a graphics house. Common sense is a `plus` in that field, or any for that matter. Yeah, you've got your work cut out for ya Bro. I usually always save a JPG when working with EPS, just in case it ever went sour or AWOL. Cheers

Comment: Added note: If you have Adobe Illustrator or know someone that does, you'll be able to open the original source files and export to bitmap (JPG, etc.) should you ever need to resort to that. Inkscape might also work, and Adobe ImageReady.

Comment: There is a website the converts them but they have a size cap and it was just something I came across in my search, http://epsviewer.org/ConvertEpsToJpg.aspx

Comment: I think I may have seen that one in the past. The 100mb cap's not bad, do you have EPS's that are larger than that?

Comment: Some of them are but I am not going to sit and convert over 500gb of EPS files.  Does anyone know of a plugin to view eps in browser? I was trying to search if I could import it onto HTML5 canvas but just started looking at that this morning. I think the end all is going to be convert to 100px X 100px thumbnails in jpeg and if they want the original they can follow the path. Such a shame that there isnt any simple way to do this.

Comment: Ouch. If they've got the `coin` to hire a graphics guy (such as I lol) to convert them all, it's just a matter of keeping up with JPG conversion/thumbnails later. One thing you probably could do is, to see if you can find an EPS to SVG converter. I believe there are plugins (even built-in for Firefox) for SVG graphics. (Food for thought).